# Efficient method to perform a groupby count on unique values in a df

Tags: python, pandas

The code below aims to return a `df` that counts the number of points positive and negative FROM a reference point `(mainX, mainY)`. This is determined by the `Direction`. These are separated into two groups `(I, J)`. The points are located in `X,Y` with each having a relative `Label`.

So I split the points up into their respective groups. I then subset the `df` into positive/negative df's using a query. These df's are then grouped by time and counted to a separate column. These df's are then concatenated.

All this seems to be very inefficient. Especially if I have numerous unique values in `Group`. For example, I have to replicate the querying sequence onward to return counts for `Group J`.

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish the intended output?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Time' : ['09:00:00.1','09:00:00.1','09:00:00.1','09:00:00.1','09:00:00.1','09:00:00.1','09:00:00.2','09:00:00.2','09:00:00.2','09:00:00.2','09:00:00.2','09:00:00.2'],
        'Group' : ['I','J','I','J','I','J','I','J','I','J','I','J'],                  
        'Label' : ['A','B','C','D','E','F','A','B','C','D','E','F'],                 
        'X' : [8,4,3,8,7,4,2,3,3,4,6,1],
        'Y' : [3,6,4,8,5,2,8,8,2,4,5,1],
        'mainX' : [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5],
        'mainY' : [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5],
        'Direction' : ['Left','Right','Left','Right','Left','Right','Left','Right','Left','Right','Left','Right']
    })

# Determine amount of unique groups
Groups = df['Group'].unique().tolist()

# Subset groups into separate df's
Group_I = df.loc[df['Group'] == Groups[0]]
Group_J = df.loc[df['Group'] == Groups[1]]


# Separate into positive and negative direction for each group    
GroupI_Pos = Group_I.query("(Direction == 'Right' and X > mainX) or (Direction == 'Left' and X < mainX)").copy()
GroupI_Neg = Group_I.query("(Direction == 'Right' and X < mainX) or (Direction == 'Left' and X > mainX)").copy()

# Count of items per timestamp for Group I
GroupI_Pos['GroupI_Positive_Count'] = GroupI_Pos.groupby(['Time'])['Time'].transform('count')   
GroupI_Neg['GroupI_Negative_Count'] = GroupI_Neg.groupby(['Time'])['Time'].transform('count')   

# Combine Positive/Negative dfs
df_I = pd.concat([GroupI_Pos, GroupI_Neg], sort = False).sort_values(by = 'Time')

# Forward fill Nan grouped by time
df_I = df_I.groupby(['Time']).ffill()
```

Intended Output:

```
          Time Group Label  X  Y  mainX  mainY Direction  GroupI_Positive_Count  GroupI_Negative_Count  GroupJ_Positive_Count  GroupJ_Negative_Count
0   09:00:00.1     I     A  8  3      5      5      Left                      1                      2                      1                      2
1   09:00:00.1     J     B  4  6      5      5     Right                      1                      2                      1                      2
2   09:00:00.1     I     C  3  4      5      5      Left                      1                      2                      1                      2
3   09:00:00.1     J     D  8  8      5      5     Right                      1                      2                      1                      2
4   09:00:00.1     I     E  7  5      5      5      Left                      1                      2                      1                      2
5   09:00:00.1     J     F  4  2      5      5     Right                      1                      2                      1                      2
6   09:00:00.2     I     A  2  8      5      5      Left                      2                      1                      0                      3
7   09:00:00.2     J     B  3  8      5      5     Right                      2                      1                      0                      3
8   09:00:00.2     I     C  3  2      5      5      Left                      2                      1                      0                      3
9   09:00:00.2     J     D  4  4      5      5     Right                      2                      1                      0                      3
10  09:00:00.2     I     E  6  5      5      5      Left                      2                      1                      0                      3
11  09:00:00.2     J     F  1  1      5      5     Right                      2                      1                      0                      3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my take on it

```
s = (((df.Direction.eq('Right') & df.X.gt(df.mainX)) | 
      (df.Direction.eq('Left')  & df.X.lt(df.mainX)))
     .replace({True: 'Pos', False: 'Neg'}))

df_count = df.groupby(['Time', 'Group', s]).size().unstack([1, 2], fill_value=0)
df_count.columns = df_count.columns.map(lambda x: f'Group{x[0]}_{x[1]}')

df_final = df.merge(df_count, left_on='Time', right_index=True)

Out[521]:
          Time Group Label  X  Y  mainX  mainY Direction  GroupI_Neg  \
0   09:00:00.1     I     A  8  3      5      5      Left           2
1   09:00:00.1     J     B  4  6      5      5     Right           2
2   09:00:00.1     I     C  3  4      5      5      Left           2
3   09:00:00.1     J     D  8  8      5      5     Right           2
4   09:00:00.1     I     E  7  5      5      5      Left           2
5   09:00:00.1     J     F  4  2      5      5     Right           2
6   09:00:00.2     I     A  2  8      5      5      Left           1
7   09:00:00.2     J     B  3  8      5      5     Right           1
8   09:00:00.2     I     C  3  2      5      5      Left           1
9   09:00:00.2     J     D  4  4      5      5     Right           1
10  09:00:00.2     I     E  6  5      5      5      Left           1
11  09:00:00.2     J     F  1  1      5      5     Right           1

    GroupI_Pos  GroupJ_Neg  GroupJ_Pos
0            1           2           1
1            1           2           1
2            1           2           1
3            1           2           1
4            1           2           1
5            1           2           1
6            2           3           0
7            2           3           0
8            2           3           0
9            2           3           0
10           2           3           0
11           2           3           0
```

Comment: Thanks Andy. Love the boolean mask instead of subsetting the df.

Answer (score 1):

```
I used [numpy.select][1] to filter based on the conditions, 
pivot table gets us the count of positive and negatives
and then merge the tables using the join method.

pos1 = (df.Direction=='Right') & (df.X.ge(df.mainX))
pos2 = (df.Direction=='Left') & (df.X.le(df.mainX))
neg1 = (df.Direction=='Right') & (df.X.le(df.mainX))
neg2 = (df.Direction=='Left') & (df.X.ge(df.mainX))
cond_list = [(pos1|pos2),(neg1|neg2)]
choice_list = ['pos','neg']

df['choices'] = np.select(cond_list,choice_list)

R = df.copy().pivot_table(index='Time',
                          columns= 'Group','choices'],values='Label',
                          aggfunc='count')

R.columns = R.columns.to_flat_index()

#better than hardcoding the columns
R.columns = ['Group'+'_'.join(i)+'_count' for i in R.columns]


df
.set_index('Time')
.join(R).fillna(0)
.reset_index()
.drop('choices',axis=1)


Time Group Label  X  Y  mainX  mainY Direction  \
0   09:00:00.1     I     A  8  3      5      5      Left   
1   09:00:00.1     J     B  4  6      5      5     Right   
2   09:00:00.1     I     C  3  4      5      5      Left   
3   09:00:00.1     J     D  8  8      5      5     Right   
4   09:00:00.1     I     E  7  5      5      5      Left   
5   09:00:00.1     J     F  4  2      5      5     Right   
6   09:00:00.2     I     A  2  8      5      5      Left   
7   09:00:00.2     J     B  3  8      5      5     Right   
8   09:00:00.2     I     C  3  2      5      5      Left   
9   09:00:00.2     J     D  4  4      5      5     Right   
10  09:00:00.2     I     E  6  5      5      5      Left   
11  09:00:00.2     J     F  1  1      5      5     Right   

GroupI_neg_count  GroupI_pos_count  GroupJ_neg_count  \
0                     2.0                    1.0                    2.0   
1                     2.0                    1.0                    2.0   
2                     2.0                    1.0                    2.0   
3                     2.0                    1.0                    2.0   
4                     2.0                    1.0                    2.0   
5                     2.0                    1.0                    2.0   
6                     1.0                    2.0                    3.0   
7                     1.0                    2.0                    3.0   
8                     1.0                    2.0                    3.0   
9                     1.0                    2.0                    3.0   
10                    1.0                    2.0                    3.0   
11                    1.0                    2.0                    3.0   

GroupJ_pos_count  
0                     1.0  
1                     1.0  
2                     1.0  
3                     1.0  
4                     1.0  
5                     1.0  
6                     0.0  
7                     0.0  
8                     0.0  
9                     0.0  
10                    0.0  
11                    0.0
```